# Centering Embedded Image

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to adjust this code so that the imported image aligns with the top/**CENTER** of the cell vs the top/**LEFT**. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Test()
Dim MySht As Worksheet
Dim MyPic As Shape
Dim MyLeft AsSingle, MyTop AsSingle


 MyTop = [C14].Top
 MyLeft = [C14].Left


Set MySht = ActiveSheet
Set MyPic = MySht.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\Sryan\Desktop\Untitled.png", _
msoFalse, msoTrue, MyLeft, MyTop,-1,-1)
' ^^^ LinkTo SaveWith -1 = keep size

' now resize pic
MyPic.Height =100

EndSub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `[C14].Left + 0.5 * [C14].Width`.

---

If the image has width `W` and you want to put match the middle of the image with the middle of the cell, then the position of the middle of the cell is still `[C14].Left + 0.5 * [C14].Width`, and you have to subtract half the width, so the image Left has to be

`[C14].Left + 0.5 * ([C14].Width - W)`

Comment: Hi cub- I appreciate the suggestion, but code just indents the image to the middle of the cell versus matching the center of the image with the center of the cell.  Do you have any thoughts on how I could incorporate:  (cell.width-image.width)/2? So if a cell was 100 pixels and the image was 80, it would indent 10 pixels.  Also I need to first resize the image so that the height is equal to 100 pixels.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code would be bellow.

```
Sub Test()
Dim MySht As Worksheet
Dim MyPic As Shape
Dim MyLeft As Single, MyTop As Single
Dim myFn As String, w As Single, h As Single

myFn = "C:\Users\Sryan\Desktop\Untitled.png"
Set MySht = ActiveSheet
With MySht.Range("c14")
    MyTop = .Top + 1
    MyLeft = .Left + 1
    w = .Width - 2
    h = .Height + 2
End With

Set MyPic = MySht.Shapes.AddPicture(myFn, msoFalse, msoTrue, MyLeft, MyTop, w, h)

End Sub
```

**Bellow code is a way to keep the aspect ratio.**

```
Sub Test()
Dim MySht As Worksheet
Dim MyPic As Shape
Dim MyLeft As Single, MyTop As Single
Dim myFn As String, w As Single, h As Single

myFn = "C:\Users\Sryan\Desktop\Untitled.png"
Set MySht = ActiveSheet

GetPicture myFn, MySht.Range("c14")

End Sub
Sub GetPicture(strPic As String, rngPic As Range)
    Dim Pic As Picture
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim l As Single, t As Single, w As Single, h As Single
    Dim Rt As Single, myL As Single, myT As Single

    Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strPic)

    With Pic
        h = .Height
        w = .Width
    End With
    Pic.Delete

    With rngPic
        If h = w Then
            t = .Top
            l = .Left
            w = .Width
            h = .Height
        ElseIf h > w Then
            Rt = w / h
            t = .Top
            h = .Height
            w = .Height * Rt
            myL = (.Width - w) / 2
            l = .Left + myL
        ElseIf h < w Then
            Rt = h / w
            w = .Width
            h = .Width * Rt
            If h > .Height Then
                h = .Height
                w = h / Rt
            End If
            myL = (.Width - w) / 2
            myT = (.Height - h) / 2
            l = .Left + myL
            t = .Top + myT
        End If


        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(strPic, msoCTrue, msoCTrue, l, t, w, h)

     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dy Lee - Is there a way to keep the aspect ratio?  I'd like to resize the image first to 100 pixels and then center.  Thanks